# AngularJS comparing with $$hashkey

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to compare an object included within a repeater to an object just returned from the server.

Because the repeated object contains the hashkey property angular.equals evaluates to false.

I guess i could just delete the property but i don't know if their is an angular way to handle this.

thanks

Comment: Are you sure the objects are equivalent? `angular.equals` "During a property comparison, properties of function type and properties with names that begin with $ are ignored."

Comment: hmm they should be. i save the parent object then compare two child objects. i'll double check thx

Answer (score 8):

There is an angular way to handle this. You need to **track by** a unique field that each object has. For example instead of:

```
item in items
```

Do:

```
item in items track by item.id
```

Checkout angular's documentation regarding [ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) and $$hasKey

Comment: Idea angular.equals should ignore $$hashKey but in my case it does not. I have an object which is bind with ng-repeat and other object is received from server. Both are same except $$hashKey but angular.equals always returns false. If I remove binding from ng-repeat, angular.equals evaluates to true.

Comment: @Marco does this answer your question?